# Не отображается табличка в HtmlTextView

Tags: android, html, table, placeholder

Пишу таблицы для своего приложение с помощью [сайта быстрого перевода текста](https://wordtohtml.net/) в HTML текст отображается без ошибок но вот на месте таблички стоит надпись table placeholder и текст который в таблице не отображается. 
Как сделать что бы HTML отображал таблицу
Вот библиотека которую я использую

```
 implementation 'org.sufficientlysecure:html-textview:3.2'
```

Comment: В описании библиотеки сказано что [таблицы не поддерживаются](https://github.com/SufficientlySecure/html-textview#support-for-html-tables), можно лишь заменить их ссылкой и при её нажатии отправлять в `WebView`. А, собственно, тогда не проще сразу всё в `WebView` и выводить... Или поискать что-то другое, если считаете что `WebView` слишком громоздкая для вашей задачи.

Comment: @woesss есть какая то другая HTML отображалка которая буде отображать таблицы на андроид. Извините за тавтологию